# Acf numeric value filed if empty show message

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, code-snippets

I have a problem with [advanced custom fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/#field-types).

I have a numeric value field "**price**" when I don't put a **price** it displays **$0.00** instead of

"**please contact us**"

despite my css

```
.price:empty {
  content: 'please contact us';
}
```

I use this code to format the value

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=property_price', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
$value = number_format((floatval($value)), 2, ',', ',');
return $value;
}
```

How to solve this problem ?

does php understand **empty value** as zero?

or do I need to include something extra in my code to tell him **if empty** = displays a message?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that it's not a very good idea to change the value to "please contact us" since it is a string, and your field an integer. Would help if you change the *display* of the value? If you're using Woocommerce, `woocommerce_product_get_price` filter can be an option.

Comment: nope i'm not using woocommerce

Comment: Is the dollar sign ($) added by your theme or another plugin? I think in a way to solve your problem, but just filtering the acf field value would make something like: "$please contact us"

Comment: dollar $ is add by css :before or :after it is purely cosmetic .
everything is controlled by me I suspect the **floatval** which generates a zero. we have to wait for a php expert to explain what's going on

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=property_price', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
  if(empty($value)){
    return 'please contact us';
  }
  $value = '$' . number_format((floatval($value)), 2, ',', ',');
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: Oh waw it worked straight away ! millions thanks! 
now I realize I  have another problem
instead of doing multiple css :after and :before **$** in multiple places Like archives, single pages, loops etc ..., it is not manageable this way

I must include them in the code directly
do you have an idea ?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, see if that works for you. Now if there's a valid price, the sign is returned.

Comment: perfect ! very professional, it works very well :)

Answer (score 0):

add_filter('acf/format_value/type=number', 'fix_number', 20, 3);

function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {

// 判断是否有值
if(!empty($value)){

```
// 格式化数字
$value = number_format($value);
```

}

return $value;

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).